# How to use Regex in a While If statement? Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I'm new to programming and I've run into an issue. We have to use Perl to write a script that opens a file, then loops through each line using a Regex - then print out the results. The opening of the file and the loop I have, but I can't figure out how to implement the Regex. It outputs 0 matched results, when the assignment outline suggests the number to be 338. If I don't use the Regex, it outputs 2987, which is the total number of lines - which is correct. So there's something incorrect with the Regex I just can't figure out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's what I have thus far:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $i = 0;
my $filename = 'C:\Users\sample.log.txt';

open (fh, '<', $filename) or die $!;

while(<fh>) {
    if ($filename=~ /(sshd)/){
        $i++;
    }
}

close(fh);
print $i;
```

Comment: `if ($filename=~ /(sshd)/)` should be  `if (/sshd/)`

Comment: Wow, thanks!  So you don't have to use a regex command in perl? Every resource I used to try and find an answer used "=~" following the Regex, that's not always necessary?

Comment: That's not what he meant. There are two operators involved in a regex match. `/foo/` is an abbreviation for `m/foo/`, the [m//](https://perldoc.pl/perlop#m/PATTERN/msixpodualngc) operator which does a regex match (as opposed to `s///` which does a substitution, or `tr///` which doesn't have to do with regex at all). The second operator that works in tandem with that is `=~`, which binds the operation to a string it will operate on. If there is no string bound to it, it will operate on `$_`, which is also what while(<>) assigns to if you don't assign it to something else (but you should).

Answer (score 2):

Consider this piece of code of yours:

```
while(<fh>) {
    if ($filename=~ /(sshd)/){
        $i++;
    }
}
```

You are indeed looping through the file lines, but you keep checking if the *file name* matches your regex. This is clearly not what you intend.

You meant:

```
while (my $line = <fh>) {
    if ($line =~ /sshd/){
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Parentheses around the regex seem superfluous (they are meat to capture, while you are only matching).

Since expression `while (<fh>)` assigns the content of the line to special variable `$_` (which is the default argument for regexp matching), this can be shortened as:

```
while (<fh>) {
    $i++ if /sshd/;
}
```

Comment: Also `perl -lne '$i++ if /sshd/ }{ print $i' C:\Users\sample.log.txt`  Or use `END{}` rather than eskimo kiss.

Comment: And that's equivalent to `grep -c sshd C:\Users\sample.log.txt` ... but I assume this perl code will grow.

Comment: @stevesliva: indeed! But OP does not seem to be looking for a one-liner here, so I provided an answer as a perl script.

Answer (score 0):

OP code has some errors which I've correcte

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $i = 0;
my $filename = 'C:\Users\sample.log.txt';

open my $fh, '<', $filename
        or die "Couldn't open $filename";

map{ $i++ if /sshd/ } <$fh>;

close($fh);

say "Found: $i";
```